# How can I resolve an issue with a website (using flex-box and max-width) re-sizing inappropriately on IE 11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem with a site redesign on IE 11 - the portfolio section slowly shrinks, aligns left, and eventually disappears when the window is less than 768px wide, and when clicking on a portfolio item, the content enlarges way beyond the viewport. There is no such issue with Chrome or Firefox.

This is the first time I have used flexbox, so I'm guessing that is the problem.

The site:
[test.nicklemmon.com](http://test.nicklemmon.com)

Thanks!
I was able to resolve the issue where the content disappears entirely - it had something to do with usingn max-width on a div (though this didn't effect the other browsers)

Isolating where I think the left-aligning problem lies...I'm using SASS + Bourbon:

```
        .work-container .row {
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -moz-box;
          display: box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -moz-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
          -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
          box-orient: horizontal;
          -webkit-flex-direction: row;
          -moz-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
          -ms-flex-direction: row;
          -webkit-box-align: center;
          -moz-box-align: center;
          box-align: center;
          -webkit-align-items: center;
          -moz-align-items: center;
          -ms-align-items: center;
          -o-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
          -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -moz-box-pack: center;
          box-pack: center;
          -webkit-justify-content: center;
          -moz-justify-content: center;
          -ms-justify-content: center;
          -o-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
          max-width: 100%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .work-container .row {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
        box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -moz-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -moz-justify-content: center;
        -ms-justify-content: center;
        -o-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;
        box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        -o-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
        -moz-box-lines: multiple;
        box-lines: multiple;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }
}
```

I'm also temporarly allowing overflow to see if anyone else can see where the issue lies. Looking at the code again, some of this is redundant.

OK, looking at it again I see where the problem lies, but I'm still not sure how to resolve it:

```
.work-belt {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
}
```

If I take out display: flex, then the shrinking/left-aligning behavior goes away, but then the layout breaks on Chrome and Firefox.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: IE11 fully supports flexbox pretty well. Can you isolate the issue and reproduce it in code here in your question?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation problem, only provide the compiled CSS.

Comment: Fair enough! Just swapped it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well nevermind then - I resolved the issue myself:

For some reason IE required the following properties on the container (.work-belt) whereas Chrome and Firefox didn't:

```
.work-belt {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  box-lines: multiple;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
}
```

I would be interested to hear why there is a discrepancy there, but at least it's resolved.